# How to show that a given probability is strictly greater than zero for some Gaussian process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-analysis

I am currently reading [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.10935.pdf) paper and there is a particular step I am not getting.

First of all there is a process $Y$ defined by
$$
Y_t = \int_0^t K(t,s)dW_s,
$$
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion and $K$ is some kernel (think of $K(t,s) = \alpha (t-s)^{\alpha -1}$ for now).

Let $C_K(t,t')= \int_0^{t \land t'}K(t,s)K(t',s)ds$ and $\theta_T(h):= \sup_{0\leq t,t'\leq T,|t-t'|\leq h} \{C_K(t,t) + C_K(t',t'),-2C_K(t,t')\}^{1/2}$. Now there are two propositions in the paper. The first one states that if
$$
C_K(t,t) < \infty, \quad \text{for} \quad t > 0
$$
$$
\theta_T(0^+) = 0 \quad \text{and} \quad \int_{0^+} \sqrt{\ln(1/u)}d\theta_T(u) < \infty
$$
Then $Y$ admits a continuous version.

The second proposition states that if (in addition to the above assumptions) $K(t-s) = \hat K(t-s)$ for $s \leq t$ and for all $\epsilon > 0$ we have $\int_0^\epsilon |\hat K| > 0$. Then for each $T \geq 0$, the law of $Y$ has full support in $C_0^T:= \{y \in C([0,T],\mathbb{R}): y(0) = 0\}$.

Later in the paper they conclude that $\mathbb{P}[Y_t \geq \lambda t -1, t \in [0,T] ]> 0$, with reference to the above (where $\lambda > 0$). I am not sure why this follows? Do we have (or have to assume) that $Y$ is a gaussian process? If so, why can we conclude that the probablility is strictly greater than 0 in the light of the above propositions?
(This generalises the statement for Brownian motion, i.e. when $K \equiv 1$, where the statement is clear to me).

Comment: The set of paths $\{y\in C_0^T: y(t) > \lambda t-1,\forall t\in[0,T]\}$ is open in $C_0^T$, for each $\lambda >0$.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and thanks for the comment. Ok, now we estimate $\mathbb{P}[Y_t \geq \lambda t-1, t \in [0,T]] \geq \mathbb{P}[Y_t > \lambda t-1, t \in [0,T]]$ and now it would suffice to show that the probability of $Y$ not leaving an open set in $[0,T]$ is positive. But how can one establish that?

Comment: You've stated that the law of $Y$ has "full support", meaning that $\Bbb P[Y\in G]>0$ whenever $G$ is a non-empty open subset of $C^T_0$.

Comment: Thanks! I get it now.